# PyPDF2 - merging pages from two different PDF files is not working

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, pypdf

I'm trying to merge pages from two PDF files into a single PDF with a single page. So I tried the code below that uses PyPDF2:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader,PdfFileWriter
import sys
f = sys.argv[1]
k = sys.argv[2]
print f,k
file1 = PdfFileReader(file(f, "rb"))
file2 = PdfFileReader(file(k, "rb"))
output = PdfFileWriter()
page = file1.getPage(0)
page.mergePage(file2.getPage(0))
output.addPage(page)
outputStream = file("join.pdf", "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

It produces a single file and single page with the contents of page 1 from file 1, but I don't find any data from page 1 of file2. Seems like it didn't get merged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On using your exact same code, I am able to get two `PDF` as merged `PDF` in one page with the second one overlapping the first one, I referred this [link](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/manipulating-pdfs-with-python/167) for detailed information.

And, instead of `file()` it is better to use `open()` as per this [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file), so I did that.

Also, I made slight changes in your code but still, the working is same and correct on my machine. I am using `Ubuntu 16.04` with `python 2.7`.

Here is the code:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader,PdfFileWriter
import sys

f = sys.argv[1]
k = sys.argv[2]
print f, k
file1 = PdfFileReader(open(f, "rb"))
file2 = PdfFileReader(open(k, "rb"))
output = PdfFileWriter()
page = file1.getPage(0)
page.mergePage(file2.getPage(0))
output.addPage(page)

with open("join.pdf", "wb") as outputStream:
    output.write(outputStream)
```

I hope this helps.

---

**UPDATE:**

Here is the code which is working for me and merging the two pdf's page as single page.

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
from pdfnup import generateNup

initial_output = PdfFileWriter()
input1 = PdfFileReader(open("landscape1.pdf", "rb"))
input2 = PdfFileReader(open("landscape2.pdf", "rb"))

initial_output.addPage(input1.getPage(0))
initial_output.addPage(input2.getPage(0))

# creates a new pdf file with required pages as separate pages.
initial_output.write(file("final.pdf", "wb"))

# merges newly created pdf file pages as one.
generateNup("final.pdf", 2, "intermediate.pdf")

# overwrite and rotates the final.pdf
final_output = PdfFileWriter()
final_output.addPage(PdfFileReader(open("intermediate.pdf", "rb")).getPage(0).rotateClockwise(90)) 
final_output.write(open("final.pdf", "wb"))
```

I have added a new code and now it is also rotating the final pdf. Output PDF that you need is `final.pdf`

And here is the [Google Drive link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B45dOHQNtoKLQVVDcHl0RUhDZHM) to my drive for `PDF` files. Also, I made slight changes into `pdfnup.py` for compatibility with my system for `Immutableset` if you want to use the same file then, you can find it too in the drive link above.

Comment: May I get the sample pdf files for input? I still getting the second page only,..

Comment: Sure, here is the link from my Google Drive:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B45dOHQNtoKLQVVDcHl0RUhDZHM

Comment: is that the default functionality of mergePage? It seems like the second file is placed on top of first one.. I thought it would merge contents of two pages into one vertically.. like if we have two pages with contents "foo"*100 in first page and and bar*100 in second page and it would merge pages (first half of first page at the top and first half of second page at the bottom) of joined page. So "foo" comes at the top and "bar" comes at the bottom. Is there any way to do like this?

Comment: Yes, merge overlaps the data you can read about merge here: [http://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileMerger.html#PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger.merge]

Comment: What you are looking for is I guess is another python package namely: `pdfnup`. Refer this: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfnup and here is the same solution from [StackOverflow] itself: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140466/shrink-and-merge-pdfs-in-python). Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Is your question solved? If yes you can give bounty. And mark as correct. If no, then do respond here. Thanks.

Comment: @Shubam I have tried pdfnup but it creates crease different pages instead of one.. If you provide an example along with the input files joined, then I will offer the bountry for you.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I have added new code you can try it and the link for the drive is also there.

Comment: it creates two pages on out.pdf but I want only one page which contain(1st half from the first file + 1st half from the second file)

Comment: check `merged.pdf`. It has both pages merged.

Comment: it adds horizontally but I want it to add vertically. I know this is because of the page size. So that we can achieve what I want ie, exactly splitting a single page into two and merge it vertically so that It looks like the origin pdf.

Comment: Is your split files are in landscape style.?

Comment: no, it would be in potrait.. I want the final page in potrait format.

Comment: What if I rotate the merged.pdf? Will that do?

Comment: Rotating `merged.pdf` by `python` is an easy task. If the program above is letting you achieve the final outcome you want then rotation is not a big deal.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I have added the code to rotate the PDF and also reduced some variables. Now you can try this code and get the desired outcome in `final.pdf`. I have attached these files to my drive so that you can access them from there.

Comment: If you got what you want then please mark it as correct or do respond here. thanks.

Comment: you're almost there but it misses something. What you have done is merging two pages vertically (merging process is ok) but what I want is, take a two pages pdf, split the first page into two and second page into two. Now I want 1st and 3rd page to get merged. I already done splitting through pypdf2, so it's not a big deal for you..

Comment: @AvinashRaj Okay let me try this.

Comment: @AvinashRaj May, I get the code and PDF file on which you are trying to work on. So I can use it and provide you the proper output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131303/discussion-between-avinash-raj-and-shubham-namdeo).

Comment: is this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14996758/3297613 code works for you? I can't get the bullet in pdf.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Sorry for this late reply. Yes, the code is working for me. and I am able to get exact same bullets as shown in the image with the link you shared. And with you, I guess it might be the case of colors or you may have missed something from import.

Answer (score -1):

```
def merge_page(self, output_pdf,*input_pdfs):
    a=len(input_pdfs)
    print (a)
    merge = PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger()
    outputStream = open(output_pdf, "wb")
    if a<2:
        raise Exception ("Need Atleast Two Pdf for Merging")

    else:
        for x in input_pdfs:
            merge.append(open(x,"rb"))
        merge.write(outputStream)
    outputStream.close()
```

For me this code is working in PyCharm and it can take n no of pdf files for merging into single pdf file but the no should be 2 or more less than that will give error.